# unable to stop gerrit at version 3.2.1

Tags: gerrit

I just installed gerrit 3.2.1
After I start it, i failed to open my site with bellow errors:

```
The HTTP server did not provide the username in the Authorization header when it forwarded the request to Gerrit Code Review.

If the HTTP server is Apache HTTPd, check the proxy configuration includes an authorization directive with the proper location, ensuring it ends with '/':
```

ServerName devops.adaps.corp

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location /login/>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
  Require valid-user
  ...
</Location>


AllowEncodedSlashes On
ProxyPass / http://.../ nodecode
```

So I want to stop it and check if I need to add a htpasswd file.

But... it seems unstopable.... I tried with command:

```
/work/devops/gerrit/bin/gerrit.sh stop
sudo /work/devops/gerrit/bin/gerrit.sh stop
```

I get error of :

```
Stopping Gerrit Code Review: start-stop-daemon: matching only on non-root pidfile /work/devops/gerrit/logs/gerrit.pid is insecure
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by manually kill the process recorded in pidfile